# When making a custom transition page route, how can I stop the old page from sliding away?

Tags: flutter

Im trying to make a custom animation for a new page route, where my new page fades in and scales in, and that part is working out nicely.  However, my old page will slide out leaving behind a blank white screen.   I'd like my new screen to show over the old screen with the old screen remaining just as it was

Heres what I have so far:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MyImagePageRoute(MyImageViewer(image: imgsrc)));
```

```
class MyImagePageRoute<T> extends CupertinoPageRoute<T> {
  MyImagePageRoute(this.child)
      : super(builder: (BuildContext context) => new MyImageViewer(image: ''));

  @override
  // TODO: implement barrierColor
  Color get barrierColor => Colors.transparent;


  @override
  String? get barrierLabel => null;

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return

      ScaleTransition(
      scale: animation,
      child: FadeTransition(
        opacity: animation,
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get maintainState => true;

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 500);

}
```

Comment: i would check existing `PageTransitionsBuilder`s implementations: `FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder`, `OpenUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder`, `ZoomPageTransitionsBuilder` and `CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder`

Comment: in case you cannot find the sources, they are [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f18b9281c2/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/page_transitions_theme.dart)

Comment: @pskink thanks, trying to understand it all...